# how to open same file in same tab for commandline vim

Tags: vim

I know another session said use :drop can do it but I only use command line vim. Is there a plugin can do it? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "commandline VIM"?

Comment: I know this question is ages old, but in case anyone is still looking for an answer, I guess you can do that by running `:tab drop filename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is `set switchbuf=usetab` in your `.vimrc`.

With this set you can then do `:sb <part-of-filename-or-buffer-number>` to switch to the tab or window that has that buffer open.  In this example: `:sb A`.

See `:help 'switchbuf'` for more information.

Comment: Yes, have combine with newtab( set switchbuf=usetab,newtab),  also reference http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_tab_pages

Answer (score 0):

Is `vim -o the_file the_file` what you want?

Comment: no, I mean I already open two file (A and B) in two tabs. If I input :tabe A, will create a new tab with file A, no in the old tab with file A. So that I want to find a command to always open file A in the old tab, do NOT create a new tab

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand you question correctly but:

`e` -> reloads the active file.
`e myfile.txt`-> opens another file in the active tab.